# SSIS - How to populate a variable with a value from a flat file

Tags: variables, ssis, flat-file

I am looking to take a value from a flat file - it is the only value on the file - and pass it on to a variable for use in another DFT in my package.  Because of limitations with the Dts.Wrapper in the script component editor, I don't think I will be able to use a script component to complete this task.

Is there even a way to do this without writing a script?

Thanks much!

Taylor

Answer (score 0):

Use a different data flow.

Make the file a CSV source with no header row. Add a derived column to add row numbering (using a variable).  Then do a Conditional Split to add one row to the

At the end of the data flow, use a Script Component and put the value into your variable.

Comment: I can't do that because the SSIS application on my computer doesn't have the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts correctly working on it. Is there a way to do it without script component?  Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the flat file to create a database table? 
You could then read this data into a variable using "Execute SQL task"
The table could be deleted at the end of the control flow.